# Fridge cools but does not whirr

Tags: refrigerator

My fridge started to act strangely. It stopped whirring and the light does not work either. But it does work, it is cold actually. Could this be some ventilation issue?

Comment: The whirring you speak of is likely the fan underneath forcing air over the coils.  The fridge will likely still cool, but with reduced efficiency, slower cooling and may not be able to keep up under high demand.  You'll need to troubleshoot if it is the inside or outside fan and repair it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'd focus on fixing the light; if it isn't a bulb replacement, and the door switch isn't the problem, then perhaps they have the same cause.